# String operations not working with special characters

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, python-2.x

I opened a text file using utf-8 encoding. I am trying to do operations on the strings like `line[0]`, but it is not working correctly because of special characters in the text file. Most of the time, it does not return anything.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('test_2014.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as document:
    OnCode = False
    for line in document:
        conv = line.encode('utf-8')
        print conv[0]
```

If I try this with a text file that says:

```
Hello
!
```

it will return `H` and `!`.

If I try this with a text file that says:

```
Hello
!
§
```

it only prints `H`.

Comment: On a side note, I noticed a whitespace before `§`

Comment: open the textfile in notepad ++ and set its encoding to "utf-8" without bom

Comment: where's the bit where you open and read the file?

Comment: Ask yourself if you provided enough info for anyone to reproduce the issue. Without the minimal example, your question is off-topic. Also note that you should replace the file input using hardcoded strings. BTW: Consider upgrading to Python 3.

Comment: Remember to include what you want it to do

Comment: conv[0] means first character of the line. what do you want it to mean?

Comment: Your examples text files are not consistent. I edited your post and put them on multiple lines but what ever you gave is not consistent with what is printed. Please give the exact output without any modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reads a full string into the variable `line` which is encoded into `conv` Since that is a string, `conv[i]` gives you one of the characters in the string. If you have more than one word in the line, then use `split()1

```
for line in document:
    conv = line.encode('utf-8')
    print conv[0]
```

When you enter *Hello* as the first line

```
>>>print conv
Hello
>>>print conv[0]
H
>>> print conv[1]
e
```

For more than one word in line

```
for line in document:
    conv = line.encode('utf-8').split(' ')
    print conv[0]
```

When you enter `Hello World` you get

```
>>>print conv
Hello World
>>>print conv[0]
Hello
>>> print conv[1]
World
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. How do I make it read each line as a line and not as one large string after encoding it?

Comment: @Shivani When you read it as a line, it is one long string. Your other lines such as § is also a string though it has only one character in it. From the way you show it, just treat each line as a string. What else would you want to do with it.

Comment: I see. I am testing this on a short text file but in the end, plan on using it for a large PDF file with lots of text. Because of that, each line will have more than one word.

Comment: @Shivani I added the instructions on how to handle multiple words on the line.

Comment: @Shivani If this answers your question hit the check button and/or the up arrow.

Comment: This helped. Thank you so much!